# Finding complete SQL text running behind locked processes in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

How can I Identify which SQL is locking the table at the time of any transition, I want to see and analyze the full SQL text.

dbcc inputbuffer (pid); is not displaying the complete SQL Text.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the SPID, then you can use this:

```
SELECT text
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
    CROSS APPLY ::fn_get_sql(sql_handle)
WHERE session_id=@spid
```

Here's the MSDN reference for [fn_get_sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189451.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Ada, I am also interested to know are there any specific condition for only those your above SQL will work.

Comment: As long as you supply a valid SPID for a currently executing request, that should work. However, you may be interested in sp_WhoIsActive - a sproc written by Adam Machanic which gives a lot more info and includes all processes currently active - basically, anything you could possibly want (filterable too). Check it out the latest version here: http://sqlblog.com/tags/Who+is+Active/default.aspx